# Como Tratar um valor Blob que esta vazio

Tags: delphi

```
var
  Streamalt, Streamalt2 : TStream;
  Jpegalt, Jpegalt2 : TJPEGImage;
  Bmpalt, Bmpalt2 : TBitmap;

begin
Streamalt := DMretaguarda.QConItem.CreateBlobStream(DMretaguarda.QConItemftpec1, bmRead);
      try
        Jpegalt := TJpegImage.Create;
        Bmpalt := TBitmap.Create;
        Jpegalt.LoadFromStream(Streamalt);
        Bmpalt.Assign(Jpegalt);
        ResizeBitMap(Bmpalt, FItem.foto1.Picture.Bitmap, FItem.foto1.Width, FItem.foto1.Height);
        FItem.foto1.Visible := true;
        Jpegalt.Free;
        streamalt.free;
      except
        FItem.foto1.Visible := false;
        Jpegalt.Free;
        streamalt.free;
      end;
end;
```

O seguinte código, trata-se de ler uma imagem no banco de dados (mysql), e jogá-lo em um TImage.

O que eu quero, é tratar este mesmo campo para verificar se está vazio, e caso esteja vazio, não envie nada para o meu TImage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var
      Streamalt, Streamalt2 : TStream;
      Jpegalt, Jpegalt2 : TJPEGImage;
      Bmpalt, Bmpalt2 : TBitmap;

    begin
if not DMretaguarda.QConItemftpec1.IsNull then
      begin
        Streamalt := DMretaguarda.QConItem.CreateBlobStream(DMretaguarda.QConItemftpec1, bmRead);
          try
            Jpegalt := TJpegImage.Create;
            Bmpalt := TBitmap.Create;
            Jpegalt.LoadFromStream(Streamalt);
            Bmpalt.Assign(Jpegalt);
            ResizeBitMap(Bmpalt, FItem.foto1.Picture.Bitmap, FItem.foto1.Width, FItem.foto1.Height);
            FItem.foto1.Visible := true;
            Jpegalt.Free;
            streamalt.free;
          except
            FItem.foto1.Visible := false;
            Jpegalt.Free;
            streamalt.free;
          end;
      end;
   end;
```

Então, na hora que postei, e achei a resposta, era só tratar um valor nulo.

Segue aí para quem precisar.

Comment: Se a versão do Delphi for >= 7, você pode fazer uses na **unit** `JPeg` no **form**, poderá colocar nele um `TDBImage` e ligado diretamente ao **field**, evitando todo este código.